# How to pass legacy C++ void pointers to and from a C++ /CX class?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

We have to deal with a legacy C++ API (API A) that returns a `void*` from one function. That `void*` needs to be passed to a C++ /CX API of ours (API B) to later be routed back into another legacy C++ API (API C) that has a function taking a `void*` parameter. Our API B never dereferences the `void*`, it just needs to hold on to it for a while to later pass it untouched to API C.

But we cannot find the correct WinRT type to cast the `void*` to. API B needs to have the C++ /CX methods public (due to being an interface implementation), so native types like `void*` cannot be part of it.

**Is there a WinRT type meant for transfering opaque pointer/handle types like that?**

**EDIT - some code to make the question clearer:**

We get a `void*` from this legacy C++ class:

```
namespace A
{
    class Source
    {
    public:

        static void* GetVoidPtr();
    }
}
```

We want to pass the WinRT representation of a `void*` to this second legacy C++ class:

```
namespace C
{
    class Target
    {
    public:

        static void SetVoidPtr(void* ptr);
    }
}
```

In between them we have the C++ /CX classes `Router`, that receives a `void*` from `Source`, and `Receiver`, that gets the WinRT representation of the `void*` since the `Receive` method must be public and passes it on the legacy class `Target`:

```
namespace B
{
    public ref class Router sealed
    {
    private:

        Receiver^ m_receiver;

        void Route()
        {
            auto ptr = SOME_CAST<SOME_TYPE>(A::Source::GetVoidPtr());
            ...
            m_receiver->Receive(ptr);
        }
    }

    public interface class IReceiver
    {
        void Receive(SOME_TYPE ptr);
    }

    public ref class Receiver sealed : IReceiver
    {
    public:

        virtual void Receive(SOME_TYPE ptr)
        {
            C::Target::SetVoidPtr(SOME_CAST<void*>(ptr));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about a *handle*.  [Platform::IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/Apps/hh755810.aspx) is the portable type.

They are exploitable, although not typically a great concern in a Store app.  EncodePointer() is a good way to stop that.  Client code can crash you by fumbling the value, handing out a simple integer that you store in a map is a countermeasure for that.

Comment: "You are talking about a *handle*" - indeed I am, that's why I mentioned "opaque pointer/handle types" above :) - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change class A to use internal: instead of public:. The internal keyword will make the GetVoidPtr() function accessible to pure C++ classes, but will make it unaccessible through the WinRT metadata.

```
namespace A
{
   class Source
    {
    internal:

        static void* GetVoidPtr();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot do that, since we need the function to be in an interface, so it must be public. Forgot to mention that the reason for must have it public was the interface - updating the question above.